# R.java won't generate. Thoroughly searched for solution. Cleaning doesn't help, I have no errors in xml or res names

Tags: r.java-file

Yesterday I walked away from my computer for lunch and when I got back my codes were filled with red lines. I discovered my R.java had been deleted after cleaning. I have spent several hours looking at solutions and nothing works. I tried cleaning, building, deleting gen folder, deleting debug file, starting a new project and putting my project files in that new project. I have no errors in xml and all of my res files are named correctly. When I start a new, blank project, the r.java is there until I usually try to reference something in the `setContentView(R.layout.xxxx.);` command.

Comment: I believe I discovered that the source of my error was in the sound files I was adding. I discovered this by starting a new project and cleaning after each res I added. After about 5 pics I added my first sound file and the r.java was deleted after the clean. When I started a new project and added a different sound file to my res and cleaned, R.java was deleted again. Removing these files from my resources and cleaning does not generate my r.java however. So I am still in trouble. Especially if I can never add a sound file to an app.

Comment: My r.java has finally regenerated. The folder that I had been putting the sounds in seemed to cause the problem. I named the folder "sounds" and it is named correctly so I don't know why this was a problem.